# How to change the the value of fontSize of a class that has the value in Viewwdith using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

When trying to use the following code to do so it results in the font size being changed to 0px

```
  var increasePercentage = x;

  for (i = 0; i< titleText.length; i++){
    titleText[i].style.fontSize = titleText[i].style.fontSize*(x/100);
  }

}
```

titleText is a document.getElementsByClass

Comment: Have you checked what the data `fontSize` contains is?  I'm pretty sure it's a string, so your sum is resulting in `NaN`.

You'd probably be better off doing this directly in the CSS, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the value of `fontSize` will be a `string` not a `number`

For example `12px`.

So you need to extract the `number` from the `string` with `parseFloat()` function.

```
var increasePercentage = x;

  for (i = 0; i< titleText.length; i++){
    titleText[i].style.fontSize = `${parseFloat(titleText[i].style.fontSize) * (x / 100)}px`;
  }

}
```

I advise you to use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) for getting the computed style of the element.

```
var increasePercentage = x;

  for (i = 0; i< titleText.length; i++) {
    const compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(titleText[i]);
    titleText[i].style.fontSize = `${parseFloat(compStyles.getPropertyValue('font-size')) * (x / 100)}px`;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped however i set a console.log statement to print what the value is however it is giving me a blank entry in the console, could this be becuase i have my font size in viewidth (vw) instead of pixels

Comment: I advice you to use `getComputedStyle`, I updated the answer, please check again.